# Find the inverse of this diagonal 4 x 4 matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

$
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & k_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & k_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I'm thinking you just have to convert this into a reduced-row echelon form like this:

$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
k_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & k_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & k_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & k_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

So the result for the inverse would be this:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{k_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac1{k_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac1{k_3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac1{k_4} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Is this right, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It is right. To check, just multiply the matrices, you get the identity matrix. Well done.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Dragon

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Daichi

Comment: Further exercise: generalize this result to an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking @Duncan, or at least how to start this. Give me a hint.

Comment: $A^{-1} = E_k.....E_2E_1I$ Where $k$ is the required number of row operations to turn $A$ into $I$.

Comment: As Duncan was saying, this is a general result that the inverse of a diagonal matrix (it it is invertible) is another diagonal matrix having entries reciprocal of the entries of the given matrix.

Comment: Oh ok. That's good to know. Thanks @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the matrix is invertible we can assume that all the $k_i$'s are non-zero. Your answer is correct. Elegant and sweet.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.